# How to load an object from the database (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

For this simple User class

```
public partial class Users
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }        
}
```

I have the WCF form to add new user working fine and checking to not allow duplicated User name

Now I have a WCF form for the logging in, 2 texbox (textBoxUser and password) and a button with this code:

```
    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I want to validate the user and password");

        using (UserDBEntities db = new UserDBEntities())
        {
            if (db.Users.Any(o => o.User == textBoxUser.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The user " + textBoxUser.Text + " exist! Now I need to check if the password is right");

                var userAccepted = db.Users.Find(textBoxUser.Text);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("User or password wrong. Try again!");
        }
```

But the line

```
var userAccepted = db.Users.Find(textBoxUser.Text);
```

is not working - I keep getting an error:

> ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.

even if User and textBoxUser.Text are strings.

And I don't know how to load the object from the database so I can check if the password is OK.

Comment: `db.Users.First(u => u.User == textBoxUser.Text)` will return the object the same way `db.Users.Any(u => u.User == textBoxUser.Text)` will return if it exists

Comment: @Rafalon Right I already get the "MessageBox.Show("The user " + textBoxUser.Text + " exist! Now I need to check if the password is right");
" working but how can I show the field Password from that object?

Comment: Check my answer for more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Enumerable.First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [List<T>.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (db.Users.Any(o => o.User == textBoxUser.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The user " + textBoxUser.Text
                  + " exists! Now I need to check if the password is right");

    User userAccepted = db.Users.First(o => o.User == textBoxUser.Text);

    MessageBox.Show(userAccepted.Password);
}
```

I would recommand changing your `Users` definition to:

```
public partial class User // note it's User and not Users
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }        
}
```

Then the answer would become:

```
if (db.Users.Any(o => o.Username == textBoxUser.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The user " + textBoxUser.Text
                  + " exists! Now I need to check if the password is right");

    User userAccepted = db.Users.First(o => o.Username == textBoxUser.Text);

    MessageBox.Show(userAccepted.Password);
}
```

So you avoid confusion between the `User` class and its `Username` field. (you could as well just name it `Name`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is working now.
I'm from a Spanish-speaking country and in Visual Studio we do not have the option to handle singular and plural, and of course I make a mistake on the transalation of the lesson.

I mean, I don´t have the "Pluralize or singularize generated object names" while creating the Entity Model